How to find out whether or not a client uses smart card to login
In a smart card login, after TCP handshake process (SYN, SYN-ACK, ACK), there are "Client Hello", "Server Hello", "Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message", and "Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message" TLS handshakes.
In which handshake stage client sends the certificate over? I guess it is right after "Client Hello".
When the client certificate is sent out, does that mean the client has already successfully logged in?

Which language?  Which libraries?


In which handshake stage client sends the certificate over? I guess it is right after "Client Hello".

There is a separate Certificate message, but only if the server actually requests a client certificate.

When the client certificate is sent out, does that mean the client has already successfully logged in?

The point of a client certificate is authentication of the client. There might be some additional authentication ("logging in") apart from a client certificate, but it is unknown if it a) exists at all and b) how it was done and c) happened already, like in another connection. Details would be specific to a specific application.

How to find out whether or not a client uses smart card to login

It is impossible to say just from looking at the exchanged messages if the client certificate is backed by a smartcard or just by a file. One can only observe that a client certificate is used, but not where it comes from.
